# How to upload file via an AJAX form in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX form in my ZF2 application. I want to handle file uploads. The JavaScript code I have written to handle the form submission can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/ddFfAfX9). How do I send the uploaded file's details to my PHP script? My current code just sends the file name.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send files via AJAX. You will need to use `hidden` iframe for this for example. And make POST request to this iframe using `target` property.

Or without jQuery you can use XHR2 using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to reach this but it's [supported](http://caniuse.com/xhr2) only in modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the new FileReader. It is already supported in most browsers. Basically it reads in the File you want to upload, so you can append it in a Post request as a string argument.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader